# angular ui-select - how to use like a selectbox?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I feel like this should be in the documentation but it's just not (actually a lot of things are not) so I'm just *very* confused.

All I need is a searchable selectbox that works exactly like the html version. I have a list of projects `[{name, id}]` and my model has a `projectId` property on it (so *just* the id, not the object).

I can't seem to figure out how I would bind by projectId like I would do with a regular selectbox. All the demos show binding of full objects, but I only need and want the id. I don't want to do anything hacky and modify my model (obviously I can add layers of indirection until this works, but I want to do this the right way).

Comment: can't you just use `on-select` and update model with controller function?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure what you mean but sounds hacky....

Comment: don't see why, it's an event available in the directive/plugin. Bind the model of the selectbox to `$scope.selected'` and use `on-select="changed()"` then update your other scope model in that controller function `$scope.changed()`

Comment: I've struggled with the select too. Seems there are several flavors depending on how/what you bind to.  Here's a link you may find helpful.  http://ngexample.com/using-ng-options-in-select/

Comment: @brewsky no typing fuzzy matching though